# Buttons in Cordova app for iOS platform doesn't work

Tags: html, ios, cordova

I have a problem with my Cordova app.

Buttons in index.html work properly at first.
But, when I run my project several time, the buttons stop working. 
They don't respond to being pressed.

One solution I read about suggested commenting out a line as shown:

```
 <!--   <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;"> -->
```

Unfortunately that didn't solve it.

**index.html**

```
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8" />
  <!--   <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;"> -->

    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> app.initialize();</script>
</head>
<body onload="engage()">
    <div class="app">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <div><button onclick="setDeviceAlias()">Set Device Alias</button></div>
        <div><button onclick="getAlias()">Get Device Alias</button></div>
        <div><button onclick="removeDeviceAlias()">Remove Device Alias</button></div>  
    </div>
</body>
```

**index.js**

```
var app = {

    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
},
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
onDeviceReady: function() {
    document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
},             
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
}
};

app.initialize();

function onResume() {}

function engage() {}

function setDeviceAlias() {
    Plugin.setDeviceAlias("someAlias",
                          function (json) {
                             alert(JSON.stringify(json));
                          }, function (json) {
                             alert(JSON.stringify(json));
                          });
}

function getAlias() {

    Plugin.getAlias(function (json) {
                      alert(JSON.stringify(json));
                    }, function (json) {
                      alert(JSON.stringify(json));
                    });
}


function removeDeviceAlias() {

    Plugin.removeDeviceAlias("",
                             function (json) {
                                 alert(JSON.stringify(json));
                             }, function (json) {
                                 alert(JSON.stringify(json));
                             });
}
```

Comment: Please provide a code example. We are not mind readers. We can't help you if you don't post some of the code that isn't working.  And if you do update your answer and post some code, please indent 4 spaces so it shows up in a grey formatted code block or click the help or ? icon in the StackOverflow question editor window.

Comment: @clearlight. I provided you my code snipet in the answer, sorry I am new in stackoverflow. Thank you for your response.